# ¿Como guardar cambios por medio de un botón pero que no lo refresque en php?

Tags: php

en esta es mi sentencia de codigo

```
 echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0;url=consulta.php?i=$_POST[i]'>";
```

como puedo quitar el refresh para que no salga de la pagina ya que estoy utilizando  modificar datos y la idea es que al momento se guarde los cambios permanezca en la pagina

Comment: Has pensado usar ajax???

Comment: si pero como podía realizarlo si me puede colaborar muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada debes tener un form o desde donde enviaras tus datos:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Insert con Ajax</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('#grabar').click(function () {
          //obtengo valores introducidos
          var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
          var email = $('#email').val();
          var clave = $('#clave').val();
          var genero = $('#genero').val();
          //envio por ajax
          $.ajax({
            url: "insertar.php",
            type: "post",
            data: { nombre: nombre, email: email, clave: clave, genero: genero},
            success: function (data) {
             alert("Datos GRabados !!");
              console.log(data);
            }
          });

        });
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-horizontal" >
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="nombre">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="correo">
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Clave</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input class="form-control" name="clave" id="clave" type="text" placeholder="clave">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Genero:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select id="genero" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">Masculino</option>
                <option value="2">Femenino</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="grabar">Grabar Datos</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

donde recibo los datos enviados x ajax(insertar.php):

```
<?php

    //Crear conexion
  $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'miBase');
    if($_POST['nombre']){
      $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $clave= $_POST['clave'];
      $genero = $_POST['genero'];

      $q = "INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, email, clave, genero) VALUES ('$nombre', '$email', '$clave', '$genero')";

      $query = mysqli_query($connection, $q);

      if($query){
          echo json_encode("ok_insert");
          }
      else {
          echo json_encode('no_ok');
          }
      }

?>
```

como veras en este archivo recibo los parametros enviados por ajax a travez del metodo POST y los inserto desde mi php(insert.php), y mediante el metodo success retorno un mensaje de exito... uso bootstrap en este caso...espero te sirva de guia..!!

Comment: muchas gracias por su colaboración